# Scan array typed DB field into array/slice in Golang

Tags: sql, go

tl; dr

I have an sql table `users` which includes an array field. How can I Scan it to variable in golang? My approach:

```
var id        int
var username  string
var activites []string
row := db.QueryRow("SELECT id, username, activities FROM users WHERE id = 1")
err := row.Scan(&id, &username, &activites)
```

Works fine for id, username.

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: postgres / (pq)

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#StringArray

Comment: thnx, it helps a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @mkopriva already pointed out, this can either be accomplished using the `StringArray` method or with the more flexible `Array` method (as it accepts an interface as the argument), both found within the `"github.com/lib/pq"` package.

As an aside, it is also a good practice to use prepared statements.

Full example:

```
var id int
var username string
var activities []string

sqlStatement := `
    SELECT
        id,
        username, 
        activities 
    FROM 
        users 
    WHERE 
        id = $1
`

stmt, err := db.Prepare(sqlStatement)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}

defer stmt.Close()

row := stmt.QueryRow(1)

err = row.Scan(
    &id,
    &username,
    pq.Array(&activities) // used here
)

if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
    // handle err
}

if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
```